# How to populate an array with integers

Tags: javascript

Please, how do you populate an array say ‘num’ with numbers not in a second array say ‘fig’? I’m trying to use a loop to have the values of the already populated array ‘fig’ compared to ‘num’ which is to be populated with integers not found in ‘fig’. I’m a bit confused.

Comment: show your code at least, it is impossible to understand clearly what you try to achieve with that description.

Comment: Which integers would you want populated? All possible integers would give you a massive array. Do you want all arrays in a given range _except_ those in `fig`?

Comment: What a question  I'd use a set for constant time access on fig, checking for presence of generated elements from, I presume 1 - 20 (let's keep it simple) and then populate num with generated elements non-existent on fig

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do an array with n numbers you can use this two ways.

```js
const arrayLength = 100;
const numberArray = [...new Array(arrayLength).keys()]
const anotherWay = new Array(arrayLength).fill().map((_, idx) => idx + 1);


console.log(numberArray, anotherWay)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fig = [-21, 0, 3, 6, 7, 42]

const min = Math.min(...fig) // or fig[0] if the the array is already sorted
const max = Math.max(...fig) // or fig[fig.length - 1] 

const num = Array.from({ length: max - min }, (_, i) => i + min)
                 .filter(el => !fig.includes(el))
```

or, saving one loop

```
const num = Array.from({ length: max - min }).reduce((acc, _, i) => {
  const curr = i + min
  if (!fig.includes(curr)) {
     return acc.concat(curr)
  }
  return acc
}, [])
```

This is assuming your range is from the smallest number in `fig` to the largest in `fig`.

Answer (score 0):

so to do this we have to do a few things:

```
1) define an existing array with numbers to avoid  
2) define length on new array
3) generate a random number and make it an integer
4) check to see if we need to avoid
5) if it's a new value add it to the second array
```

```js
var first=[55,45,35,1,2,3,4,5];
var second = [];
var i = 7;
var x;


while (i != 0){
  x = ~~(Math.random()*100);
 
   var check = false;
   for(let j=0; j<first.length;j++){
      if(x == first[j]){
         check = true;
      }
    }
   if(!check){
      second.push(x);
      i--;
      }
}
console.log(second);
```